# Is there a way to distribute windows phone 7 applications without using the windows phone 7 marketplace?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I may need to port a private application from android to windows phone 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer at the moment is "No". However, if you have a developer account, you can unlock up to 3 phones and deploy your XAP directly to them. Also there are plans to allow companies to deploy apps directly to phones without going via the marketplace, though unfortunately no official dates for this yet.

Comment: This is pretty much the situation. You can always make more accounts if that works for you and deploy to more devices. Whether the cost/admin of this is practical would be situational.

Comment: Yeah, but keep in mind, that you need a individual live-ID for every Marketplace-Account.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "official" way to do it, at least not for now. But Microsoft is in touch with developers who unlocked their phones to run home brew applications, to figure out how to make it available for developers, without prejudice the app market ecossystem.

Answer (score 0):

there's a XAP installer that you could use to install on each phone manually but if you are targeting your app to an enterprise, the benefits of installing separate from the store might be outweighed by the overhead of installing each one.

On android you would just need to tick "allow unsigned apps" somewhere in the settings, unfortunately this isn't an option with windows phones. there's no .exe facility.